# Tkinter file dialogue

Tags: python, tkinter

I am having trouble comprehending how to make a file dialogue with tkinter. I am trying to have a file dialogue open up once the program is running. The dialogue needs to have five buttons that the user can click looping till the user selects the "quit" button. Each button triggers a function from the file already open and executes, so on and so forth. For the life of me I cannot figure out how to make these buttons, much less have them trigger a function.

```
window = Tk()
window.title("Reading from a Text File")
infileName = askopenfilename()
inFile = open(infileName,"r")
fileLines = inFile.readlines()
```

Basically I have it reading from the file, but don't understand how to make the buttons. I am new to programming and don't know key things to look for on topics like this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show us your ([minimal](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) code?

Answer (score 1):

Buttons in tkinter look like this:

```
# from tkinter import *
Button(root_window, text="Text Goes here", command=function_goes_here)
```

place them on the root_window however you want to :)